# Why is /recovery at 100% and is it ok to remove those files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

## df -kh

/dev/nvme0n1p2  3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /recovery

tmpfs           1.4G   16K  1.4G   1% /run/user/120

tmpfs           1.4G   72K  1.4G   1% /run/user/1000

## cd /recovery

## ls -l

drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 29  2019 casper-B7C0-49E0

drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug 29 21:07 casper-E172-484E

drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Apr 11  2022 dists

drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Apr 11  2022 pool

-rwx------ 1 root root  171 Dec 30  2019 recovery.conf

## du -sk *

2141264 casper-B7C0-49E0

1830568 casper-E172-484E

280 dists

20824   pool

4   recovery.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure we can definitively answer you.  A standard Ubuntu install does not require a /recovery partition - so this is likely something vendor specific.  (Maybe you bought a Dell PC with Ubuntu on it ?)

casper is associated with live recovery systems - so its likely your vendor has rolled a modified version of Ubuntu with a "recovery/reinstall" partition much like Windows.  My money would be on that being the cause.  If you don't need this recovery (ie you are willing and able to reinstall from a USB key if need be) then I expect you can get rid of it.